# Spring JPA - Single Repository class with multiple JNDIs

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jndi

I am using Spring JPA Repository to connect to Oracle.

My Repository package is com.demo.infrastructure.repository;
Repository class is StoreRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface StoreRepo extends JpaRepository<StoreAttribute, String> {
    @Query("select storeAttributeName from StoreAttribute order by storeAttributeName asc")
    List<String> fetchAllStoreAttributeNames();

    List<StoreAttribute> findAllByOrderByStoreAttributeNameAsc();
}
```

**Problem**:
I am using JNDI config to configure data source. Currently it has only one JNDI entry. Now I want to use two user names for the same database, one with admin(read-write) access and the other with user(read-only) access. Both these users will access the same Repository and same entity.

I tried the solutions already available which uses two different repository packages for each data source. But I want the Repository "StoreRepo" to be the same.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryAdmin",
        basePackages = { "com.demo.infrastructure.repository" }
)
public class DataSourceAdminConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSourceAdmin")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("jdbc/myds_admin");
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryAdmin")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSourceAdmin") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).
                packages("com.demo.domain.model.entities").
                persistenceUnit("read-write").
                build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerAdmin")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryAdmin") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

I should have two classes like this with different package (Refer basePackages). But I dont want this solution instead want to use single repository package and the same repository class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me.

1) Created separate config classes one for admin user and app user each

2) Created seprate entity manager references one for admin user and app user each

3) Instantiated the same Repositoy class (without using @Repository annotation) through java code and using respective entity manager

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryAdmin"
)
public class AdminUserConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSourceAdmin")
    public DataSource dataSourceAdmin(@Value("${spring.datasource.admin-user.jndi-name}") String key) {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(key);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryAdmin")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryAdmin(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSourceAdmin") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).
                packages("com.demo.domain.model.entities").
                persistenceUnit("read-write").
                build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerAdmin")
    public EntityManager     entityManagerAdmin(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryAdmin") EntityManagerFactory
            entityManagerFactory) {
        return     SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "adminRepository")
    public StoreRepo     readWriteDimStoreRepository(@Qualifier("jpaRepositoryFactoryAdmin")
            JpaRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory) {
        return repositoryFactory.getRepository(StoreRepo.class);
    }
}





@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryApp"
)
public class AppUserConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSourceApp")
    public DataSource dataSourceApp(@Value("${spring.datasource.App-user.jndi-name}") String key) {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(key);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryApp")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryApp(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSourceApp") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).
                packages("com.demo.domain.model.entities").
                persistenceUnit("read-only").
                build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerAdmin")
    public EntityManager     entityManagerApp(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryApp") EntityManagerFactory
            entityManagerFactory) {
        return     SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "AppRepository")
    public StoreRepo     readOnlyStoreRepository(@Qualifier("jpaRepositoryFactoryApp")
            JpaRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory) {
        return repositoryFactory.getRepository(StoreRepo.class);
    }
}


//@Repository
public interface StoreRepo extends JpaRepository<StoreAttribute, String> {
    @Query("select storeAttributeName from StoreAttribute order by 
storeAttributeName asc")
    List<String> fetchAllStoreAttributeNames();

    List<StoreAttribute> findAllByOrderByStoreAttributeNameAsc();
}
```